# Mifare Plus reduced read/write range

Tags: mifare

I am using Mifare Plus cards instead of Mifare Classic and communications fail.  It looks as if the Plus cards must be nearer to the reader than the Classic cards.  Is this a known problem and are there any work-arounds short of ripping out existing equipment?